# using pfm/pfb custom fonts in my web site

Tags: php, css, fonts

I have a web site done using codeigniter php framework and mysql, i  have custom fonts in pfm/pfb type in my site, i don't know how to use them in the site, and make the appearance better as it was designed using photoshop, without that fonts it will not look nice as it was designed :(  can you guys help me to sort out this problem??

regards,
Rangana

Comment: You have to produce more detail than that - most importantly, how extensively is that font been used throughout the site?

Comment: whole site is using that font... from the main heading to the paragraphs it is using that font,,simply font is everywhere in the site....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed fonts into your website via various ways. [FontJazz](http://fontjazz.com/) is one way in which you can get this done.

> FontJazz is a tiny typographic engine
>   written in JavaScript, enabling
>   webdesigners and developers to use any
>   typeface on a website!

However you will need an [`OpenType`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenType) or [`TrueType`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType) font. I have not tried any font converters, but there are sites like [Online Font Converter](http://onlinefontconverter.com) allow you to convert font types.

Comment: fontjazz no longer works, you can use [fontsquirell](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) instead